# Code to simulate a users actions, such as logging in

Tags: php, programming-practices, web-applications

I've recently begun working on a PHP application, replacing another developer. I believed the application was using an API to communicate with a remote service but when I looked through the code I found that it was using a set of functions to actually log in, fill out forms and submit them as a user might do in a browser.

My intention is to replace this code, to use the services API instead. I've considered leaving the code as is and not replace it. It makes me wonder though is this a common practice in the software industry? To have a programme simulate a users actions in a browser to perform a set of actions? It feels to me that this is clever but poor programming, Have any other developers seen this?

Edit: Sorry, should have added this in the first place, the code I describe isn't part of a testing suite, its live code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although many may view this as generally a bad idea to implement such practices, there may have been a legitimate reason for doing this sort of thing.

As developers, many of us do like to perfect our code to minimize our technical debt; however, at the end of the day the one thing we must remember is that we are hired to meet a business goal.  Sometimes meeting those goals involve some creativity, thinking outside the box, and doing things that would be considered out of the ordinary and contrary to what the rules/guidelines say to do.

If you wanted to fix the problem, I don't see why you couldn't, but I wouldn't knock the original developer because this tactic -- back when it was implemented -- could have meant the difference between saving a client and losing a client.

Comment: Hi jmort253, Thanks for your comment. You're probably right in this case as simulating a user seems to give the application more abilities as the API currently supports.

Answer (score 3):

## No

That is *not* standard practice. If it's using an API then any automated tasks should use that same API without resorting to browser manipulation to do so.

---

Automated UI manipulation can be done with [many different tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools).

I prefer to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Selenium can be used for more then testing, even though that is what it was designed for. *If you wanted to go that route*

Comment: +1 You can use the Selenium IDE plugin to grab a quick script and run, or you can write code in a handful of languages like C# or Java to integrate them into code and even NUnit tests that can be run against automated builds.  Pretty nice.

Comment: Please avoid the overuse of formatting: your answer is fine without it.

Comment: @Mark: I simplified it, but an overuse of formatting is better then none.

Answer (score 1):

Wait - are you talking about some sort of test suite? If so, this is fairly common, although in web-app land it's probably more common to use a product like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) to simulate the user's interaction with your page instead of mocking service calls independent of the interface.

If this isn't the case, can you clear up what's actually going on?

Comment: Nope, it isn't a testing script, its a live script used to log in to a service, update some information and log out.